# I am trying to validate my mobile number(whic I picked up form my contact list) in my registration page but it is picking up space in between it

Tags: android, validation

I am trying to validate my mobile number which I am picking up from **Contac List** but **the problem is that** it is picking contact like **+91 95 xx xxxxxx** and there is space between numbers so the validation is not happening.
For now I am using this validation

```
String Mobile = "^[+]?[01]?[- .]?(\\([2-]\\d{2}\\)|[2-9]\\d{2})[- .]?\\d{3}[- .]?\\d{4}$";
```

But it's a failure.
Any help is appreciable.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the spaces then validate..

```
String phone=phone.replace(" ","");
```

Now the String phone has the text without spaces and you can compare.

Answer (score 2):

In android sdk One class is there PhoneNumberUtils by using that class you can validate your phone number:

check the documentation link [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.

```
String number = " "   //Your mobile number
number.replaceAll("[^+\\d]|(?<=.)\\+", ""));
```

This will remove all the spaces, `(`, `)` symbols

Comment: not working before replacing and after replacing are both the same when I am printing it

Comment: This should work as I'm using the same thing and it is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

you can use below code :

```
phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
try 
{
    if (phoneNumber != null)
        phoneNumber = extractDigits(phoneNumber);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{   
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where **extractDigits()** method is as :

```
public static String extractDigits(String src) 
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String firstchar = src.substring(0, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < src.length(); i++) 
    {
        char c = src.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c) || firstchar.equals("+")) 
        {
            firstchar = "";
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }
    return Checkvalidnumber(builder.toString());
}
```

where **Checkvalidnumber()** method is as :

```
public static String Checkvalidnumber(String number) 
{
    String validnumber = "";
    String Countrycode = chatPrefs.getString("countryCode", "");
    if (number.startsWith("+")) 
    {
        validnumber = number.trim();
    } 
    else if (number.startsWith("0")) 
    {
        validnumber = (Countrycode + number.substring(1, number.length())).trim();
    } 
    else 
    {
        validnumber = (Countrycode + number).trim();
    }

    return validnumber;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should try the following to remove the white spaces and then you can do the validation.

```
var str = "PB 10 CV 2662";    
str = str.replace(/ +/g, "");
```

Comment: What? This is not `Java` and does not work in `Android`.